# Object.defineProperty - prevent user changing this JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, object

I want to check in my webapp if a user is admin.

```
  var obj = { admin: false; };

  Object.defineProperty(obj, "admin", {
      writable: false
  });
```

Now, a user can go into the console, and do:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "admin", {
          writable: true
      });

obj.admin = true;
```

Is there a way to prevent this? Is there another best way to prevent executing parts of JavaScript code if a certain criteria applies? I understand, users could alter the code anyway, so I am a bit looking for good practices.

Comment: You can encapsulate property initialization just like in java accessors and mutators.

Comment: Why not `var obj = { admin: function() { return false; } };`?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: does it prevent the property from being overwritten? Not the value but the property itself.

Comment: I can do exactly the same, by defining the writable property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't prevent users (like me) from running my own javascript on my OWN browser. You need to validate, authenticate and authorize on the server-side. To authenticate and authorize a request you need to use standard mechanisms such as cookies, tokens, api access keys, etc.

Comment: Clear answer. I suspected this.

Answer (score 3):

You can create properties on objects that cannot be changed by using `Object.defineProperty`. Run the snippet below and you will see `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: admin` in the console.

```js
const User = {};

Object.defineProperty( User, "admin", {
 value: false
} );

Object.defineProperty( User, "admin", {
 value: true
} );
```

This is because `Object.defineProperty` defaults to false for writable, configurable, and enumerable. Here is an except from the MDN [Object.defineProperty documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Modifying_a_property) that talks about redefining existing properties.

> When the property already exists, Object.defineProperty() attempts to modify the property according to the values in the descriptor and the object's current configuration. If the old descriptor had its configurable attribute set to false the property is said to be “non-configurable” and no attribute can be changed (besides a one-way change of writable to false). It is not possible to switch between data and accessor property types when the property is non-configurable.

All that being said, using this as a security measure will get you in trouble. As far as securing your code goes...

1. ALWAYS validate data entering your application.
2. Minify and obfuscate your code.
3. Use [strict mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/strict-mode-javascript#rest). This will prevent a lot of unsafe practices.
4. You can use linters to help prevent more unsafe practices.
5. Read about common security pit falls. [OWASP Top Ten](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) is a good place to read about some of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.freeze`

```
var obj = { admin: false };
Object.freeze(obj);
obj.admin = true;
console.log(obj)
```

// output {admin:false}